# How to create older (2.4 not 2.5) ZF2 project with ZFTool

Tags: zend-framework, zftool2

In the current folder I've installed ZFTool

```
$ cat composer.json
{
    "require" : {
        "php" : ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zftool": "v0.1.0",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.4.8"
    }
}

$ /opt/lampp/bin/php ./vendor/bin/zf.php version
ZFTool - Zend Framework 2 command line Tool
The application in this folder is using Zend Framework 2.4.8
```

I try

## First install ZF2 and later create project

```
$ /opt/lampp/bin/php ./vendor/bin/zf.php install zf proj000 2.4.8
The ZF library 2.4.8 has been installed in proj000.

$ /opt/lampp/bin/php ./vendor/bin/zf.php create project proj000
The directory proj000 already exists. You cannot create a ZF2 project here.
```

I got the right library version but cannot create project.

## First create project and later install ZF2

```
$ /opt/lampp/bin/php ./vendor/bin/zf.php create project proj001
sh: 1: php: not found
PHP Warning:  copy(/tmp/composer.phar): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /PATH/vendor/zendframework/zftool/src/ZFTool/Controller/CreateController.php on line 85

Warning: copy(/tmp/composer.phar): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /PATH/vendor/zendframework/zftool/src/ZFTool/Controller/CreateController.php on line 85
PHP Warning:  chmod(): No such file or directory in /PATH/vendor/zendframework/zftool/src/ZFTool/Controller/CreateController.php on line 87

Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /PATH/vendor/zendframework/zftool/src/ZFTool/Controller/CreateController.php on line 87
ZF2 skeleton application installed in proj001.
In order to execute the skeleton application you need to install the ZF2 library.
Execute: "composer.phar install" in proj001
For more info in proj001/README.md

$ /opt/lampp/bin/php ./vendor/bin/zf.php install zf proj001 2.4.8
The directory proj001 already exists. You cannot install the ZF2 library here.
```

When i check proj001/composer.json i see, the ZF 2.5 settings are generated

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.5"
    }
}
```

The ZFTool created project with composer.json adapted for ZF 2.5 not ZF 2.4.
I cannot use it since I've hosting server with PHP 5.4

Answer (score 0):

I came with the following solution. 
I change generated  proj001/composer.json into 2.4 settings

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "<=2.4.9",
        "zendframework/zftool": "*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.7"
    }
}
```

Now, `php composer.phar install` installs older packages like `zendframework/zendframework (2.4.9)`